# Insert data to specific field in internal table

Tags: abap, internal-tables

I have a table let's call it "dbtab".
The name of my internal table is "it_tab".

I have a number in "new_number".

I insert that number into the empty field "laufnr" in my dbtab by using:

```
update dbtab set laufnr = new_number where laufnr = ''.
```

This Works just fine, but the changes aren't in my it_tab.

How do I update my internal table from my dbtab?

Or how do I insert a value to a specific field in my internal table?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Update your internal table when you update the database table with something like: `LOOP AT it_tab ASSIGING <tab> WHERE laufnr = ''. <tab>-laufnr = new_number. ENDLOOP.`
2. Reread the data from the database table into your internal table after you have made the update to the database.

Comment: Other writing of option 1 :
`DATA(ls_tab) = VALUE line_type_of_it_tab( laufnr = new_number ).
MODIFY it_tab FROM ls_tab TRANSPORTING laufnr WHERE laufnr = ''.`

Answer (score 0):

You could update your itab almost the same like a database table .. the only difference is, that you cannot use "update" ... use "modify" instead.

```
modify it_tab set laufnr = new_number where laufnr = '' .
```

An other option would be a simply reload of your dbtab

```
CLEAR it_tab.
SELECT * INTO it_tab FROM dbtab WHERE .... .
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things, and they are not linked.
An internal table is a representation of a dataset in a specific moment in time.
A database table is the data itself up to date.
You can manage to change any of them, but not both at the same time with a single instruction.
I will reccomend to:
- update your database
- refresh the in-memory copy
TIP: if you want to do it "the hard way", just create an object, and do both things in some sort of UPDATE method.

Answer (score 0):

hi try this hope it helps

```
LOOP AT it_tab.
   it_tab-lufnr = new_number.
   MODIFY it_tab TRASNPOTING laufnr WHERE laufnr = ''.
ENDLOOP.
```

or with conditions

```
 LOOP AT it_tab where laufnr = ''.
   it_tab-lufnr = new_number.
   MODIFY it_tab TRASNPOTING laufnr WHERE laufnr = ''.
 ENDLOOP.
```